# Configure xampp server to send email?

Tags: php, email, xampp

Is there a way that I can configure the xampp server for PHP to enable the mail() function. If not then is there a local mail server that I can install to test the mail() feature of PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure XAMPP to send mail from localhost?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost)

Answer (score 0):

On php.ini

```
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with fakemail for forwarding to your mailbox (sendmail.exe in the sendmail folder)
;sendmail_path = "\"G:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with mailToDisk, It writes all mails in the G:\xampp\mailoutput folder
sendmail_path="G:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"
```

Just uncomment the first sendmail_path and comment mailToDisk option.